# Fastboot oem get_identifier_token - FAILED (remote: unknown command)

Tags: rooting, fastboot, bootloader, htc

**Hello Everyone!**

I am trying yo unlock the bootloader with no success. Basically, the following command
Code:

```
Fastboot oem get_identifier_token
```

is hitting the error of:

```
FAILED (remote: unknown command)
```

Please, your help will be greately appreciated. Thanks in advance for reading my question.

---

**Device State:**

---

OEM unlocking: is enabled from the developers options.
USB Debugging: is enabled from the developers options.

**Software Status:** Official
**Software State:** LOCKED
**Software Security:** S-ON

**Device Information:**
**Model Number:** HTC One M9
**Android Version:** 5.1
**HTC Sense Version:** 7.0
**Software Number:** 2.10.401.1
**Baseband Version:** 01.04_U11440601_71.02.50709G_F
**Build Number:** 2.10.401.1 CL576582 release-keys
**Kernel Version:**
3.10.49-perf-g901e7f1
and@AABM #1
SMP PREEMPT

Comment: `oem` in the command implies that that command is not a fastboot standard, but is OEM specific. are you sure that your device supports this command? Can you please link to the source of whatever guide you are following?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am following the official tutorial that is listed in the main website of HTC for this specific model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my question at last after hours of researching.

We should execute the command from the **fastboot mode** (FASTBOOT USB) and not from the bootloader mode (HBOOT). This is a non-default option selectable using the volume buttons in bootloader (HBOOT) mode.That's why it was not working for me.

Comment: What is the difference between the two modes?

Comment: no different between two, mode is bootloader/fastboot, command always start with the word of "fastboot"

Comment: The only command to reboot to fastboot is `adb reboot bootloader` so What do you mean **fastboot mode (FASTBOOT USB)** and What is the command used for that?